# Typeorm cannot resolve Repositories

Tags: typeorm, nest

im trying to make a couple of scripts for starting a nestjs app with typeorm included.

one script is as the following

```
async function bootstrap() {
    
    Logger.log(`Calling method for syncing`);
    Logger.log(`Started: ${Date.now()}`);
    const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
    const userService = app.get<UserService>(UserService);
    await userService.XXXX();
    Logger.log(`Ended: ${Date.now()}`);
    await app.close();
}

bootstrap();
```

The other is the build in script

```
sync function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const corsService = app.get<CorsService>(CorsService);
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
      transform: true,
      forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
      forbidUnknownValues: true,
      transformOptions: {
        enableImplicitConversion: true,
      },
    }),
  );
  await app.startAllMicroservicesAsync();
  app.enableCors(corsService.getCorsConfig());
  await app.listen(+process.env.APP_PORT | 3005);
}
bootstrap();`
```

The error given in the first start script is

No repository for "XXXXXXX" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in current "default" connection?

Entity path looks like this:

```
entities: ['dist/**/**/*.entity.js'],
```

in project structure the path is dist/src/common/entities/xxx.entity.ts
It doesnt fit the path but that is the only way it finds the entities

Any ideas?

Comment: are missing repository dependency in that `module`?

Comment: Hello, nope i have the repo dependencies all correct